# Можно ли серриализовать и десерриализовать файл с помощью QJsonObject?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++11

Есть кастомный сетевой протокол на основе **QJsonObject**. Возникла необходимость передать файл, но поднимать отдельное соединение со своей логикой не хочется. Т.е. хочу чтобы получилось что-то типа

```
{
    size: 100500,
    data: QByteArray{...},
    is_final_chunk: false,
}
```

Но **QJsonValue** не имеет конструктора для **QByteArray**. Такое реально сделать?

Comment: мб не QByteArray хранить а строчку в hex или base64?

Comment: хм, пойду поковыряю...

Comment: `QJsonValue` - это конкретное поле JSON объекта. Чтобы сконструировать новый json-объект из массива данных надо использовать `QJsonDocument`, у которого есть статический метод  `QJsonDocument::fromJson(const QByteArray &json, QJsonParseError *error = nullptr)`

Comment: Собственно сериализация выполняется методом `QByteArray QJsonDocument::toJson(QJsonDocument::JsonFormat format) const`  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.h